# How to stream a video on home network from one pc to another using processing power of host pc?

Tags: networking, video, cpu, streaming

How do one stream a video on home network, by using the host computer to decode the video and transfer the data to the recipient computer. And yes, I know about virtual machines and Remote PC connections. I do not want to go that way.

I have a Core i3-2350M Laptop with GeForce 610M. I can play a 4K video on my laptop using hardware acceleration with MPC-HC. I have another desktop on the same home network (TP-Link 810), which is connected by Ethernet. I want to play the video on desktop without having my desktop processor (C2D 2.9 GHz) to decode the video at all. (I know it cannot handle the video efficiently.)

Comment: There will always be some encoding and decoding of video.  The video is encoded at the source and decoded to play.  If the video is streamed, it needs to be encoded in some format or another to stream it, and then decoded to play.  If the end device has low specs, then you'd want to use a codec that was easy to decode, and in general would use a higher network bandwidth.

Comment: I can't see how you are going to get to zero decoding on the desktop.  MPEG1 is probably the least impactful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a universal principle from which you cannot escape: Any computer that displays moving picture at above 15 frames per second needs a significant CPU power investment.

Aside from that, you seem to be considering the reduction of CPU load by eliminating the decoding process completely. Well, eliminating the decoding process completely for a 720p video entails transmission of:

- 1280 × 720 × 3 × 30 = 82,944,000 bytes per second (79 MB/sec)

...over the network and **processing it in the target computer** into video each second without fail! (Make no mistake, this is well within the reach of the modern mainstream hardware. But again, the modern mainstream hardware can do the decoding; since you are trying to avoid that, I suspect you don't have modern mainstream hardware on your target machine.)

As you have given no specifics about your situation and environment (e.g. operating systems, hardware involved, and network layout) I cannot possibly give you a more specific answer. In all the fairness, your question is an abstract theoretical question and the answer can only be such.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since this is my first question here, I was afraid there may be some kind of rules that may prevent me to elaborate.

Comment: Now about specifics:

I have a Core i3-2350M Laptop with GeForce 610M. I can play a 4K video on my laptop using hardware acceleration with MPC-HC.

I have another desktop on the same home network (TP-Link 810), which is connected by Ethernet. I want to play the video on desktop without having my desktop processor (C2D 2.9 GHz) to decode the video at all. (I know it cannot handle the video efficiently.)

Comment: I know it sounds impossible, but yes, 610M can handle the 4K video at 24.9 FPS. I cannot configure it to be used with VLC though; and it is not my concern. I forgot to add this in previous comment. Both OS are Windows 7 and router is 300 Mbps (I now know I would require a gigabit one from your answer).

Comment: Just some advice: Include ALL of this technical information in the original post. Super User is not a forum. We excel at specific question that include ALL relevant and necessary information and specific answers that take all of that into account. Your original question is likely to be flagged for review because it lacks this information and so is very broad. Placing all of the detailed information in the original question means we can answer your specific needs completely and with the best possible solution.